# Python Class and Attribute Error

Tags: python, class, attributeerror

Please look at the code below and the Attribute error I get. Thanks for your help.

This is the error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "ClassError.py", line 45, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__':Main()
File "ClassError.py", line 43, in Main
    printTest(i)
File "ClassError.py", line 38, in printTest
    print f.FirstName
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'FirstName'
```

CODE

```
class CompKeyData():
    def __init__(self,
        FirstName,\
        MiddleName,\
        LastName):
        self.FirstName  = FirstName
        self.MiddleName = MiddleName
        self.LastName   = LastName

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr((self.FirstName,\
                     self.MiddleName,\
                     self.LastName))

    def __iter__(self): 
        return iter((self.FirstName,\
                     self.MiddleName,\
                     self.LastName))

def ckDataClassList(dataList):
    dataObjects = []
    for FirstName,\
        MiddleName,\
        LastName in dataList:
        dataObjects.append(CompKeyData(
            FirstName,\
            MiddleName,\
            LastName))
    return dataObjects

ckData = [['John', 'Ralph', 'DuMont'], ['Jack', 'Lowry', 'Matern']] 

ckClassData = ckDataClassList(ckData)


def printTest(classData):
    for f in classData:
    print f.FirstName
return None

def Main():
    for i in ckClassData:
    printTest(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':Main()
```

Comment: Did you set `f = CompKeyData` to create an instance of the class?  I don't see that in your code. That could be the problem.

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need the `\` for line continuation.  Python automatically continues lines in unclosed parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
for i in ckClassData:
```

Each `i` is a `CompKeyData` instance. You then do:

```
printTest(i)
```

Which calls:

```
for f in classData:
```

where `classData` is the `i` you passed in.

This iterates through the individual `CompKeyData` instance, which (due to your implementation of `__iter__`) assigns `FirstName`, `MiddleName` and `LastName` in turn to `f`- each of these is a string, and doesn't have `FirstName`.

Instead, `printTest` should be:

```
printTest(classData):
    print classData.FirstName
```

You don't need to explicitly `return None`, this happens automatically if you don't explicitly `return` anything else.

Also, it is worth reading [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/); following this will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your printTest function to the following:

```
def printTest(classData):
    print classData.FirstName
```

`classData` is not a list of `CompKeyData` instances, but rather a single `CompKeyData` instance.

[PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is also certainly worth a look for python style.